# Java properties value ending in backlash

Tags: java, properties, backslash

I have a value in a Java .properties file that needs to end in a backlash. The property value should be "\\server\folder\", and I enter the value like so:

```
name=\\\\server\\folder\\
```

The trailing backslash is killing whatever property comes on the next line. Am I escaping this incorrectly?

Comment: try using forward slashes instead of backslashes

Comment: You need to provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: *try using forward slashes instead of backslashes* -- then the property value will definitely not be "\\server\folder\" as @Paul wants.

Comment: if it's a directory/file path it will work

Comment: What is all this backlash about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is in your case, but this snippet

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new FileInputStream("filename.txt"));
System.out.println(props);
```

Prints

```
{prop3=val3, prop2=val2\, prop1=val1}
```

If `filename.txt` contains

```
prop1=val1
prop2=val2\\
prop3=val3
```

---

Note that **a single** (or actually, an odd number) of `\` in the end of a property line would escape the newline character and things gets messed up.

Comment: You're right, that works fine. I apologize, what I'm actually seeing appears to be an Eclipse bug. If I put that text into a .properties file, then close it and re-open it, prop3 disappears. Make another edit and save, goodbye property value.